# How to generate url from API which data is chaning every hour PHP

Tags: php, api

I have API which changing its data on every hour. Example output:

```
{"status":true,"hash":"yJscAtmUB0IXz1SZ","link":"https://url.com/video.m3u8","thumbnail":""}
```

Actually just **link** is changing on every hour. That link I'am using to stream video via player.js. For example:

```
mysite.com/watchvideo.php?url=**link-by-api**
```

I cant figure out how to get the new link which is changing.

Comment: You'll just need to set up some kind of loop client-side that runs every hour to get the new link.

Comment: PHP sleep() allows you to indicate a number of seconds for execution to pause. In this case, to sleep for an hour, it would be sleep(3600);

Comment: Or alternatively, when you load the current video URL, store the time in some kind of cookie or client-side storage, and every time you return to the page or app, you can check to see if more than an hour has passed since the link was last downloaded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solution 1 :**

write a php code in your project that checks if it was more that 1 hours , get the new link .

```
<?php
    $dateTime = strtotime('now'); // Get current time in seconds
    $difference = $dateTime - $updatedTime; // Get Difference Between Right Now And Updated Time
    // $updatedTime is the last time api link is updated 
    // you should store the last updateDate in somewhere ...

    if ($difference >= 3600) { // 3600 seconds = 1 hour
        // Update the api link
    }
```

**Solution 2 :**

you can use cron job to run this php file every 1 hour and store the api-link into the database